# Keep Selenium Webdriver minimized while taking a screenshot

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, screenshot

I'm using selenium webdriver to load and take the screenshot of a webpage at regular intervals this way:

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap screenshot = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray));
```

however, every time this line gets called, the chrome window becomes maximized and in the way. Is there a way to have this happen in the background without chrome popping up all the time?

Comment: use phantomjs webdriver instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, running Chrome headless.

Starting from version 59 for Mac and version 60 for Windows it’s possible to run Chrome in headless mode, effectively hiding the browser window.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

...

// Create a browser with BrowserOptions
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("headless");
var driver = ChromeDriver(options);

// Do your other Selenium stuff here

// Take your screenshot
Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
ss.SaveAsFile(fileName, imageFormat);
```

Comment: thanks Marcel, I might want to be able to see the window occasionally though, perhaps there's a way to make it show in headless mode?

Comment: `ChromeOptions` is used to configure a Chrome session and is always used upon initialization of the driver, you can't change the arguments during runtime.